# Filtering Users with a globalscope

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like some assistance here.

I have a global scope to filter records based on the user role or / and company code (depending on how is logged in). See sample code below.

```
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $builder->when($user->role_id > 4, function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('id', $user->company_id);
        });

        $builder->when($user->role_id == 4, function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->where('hq_code', $user->hq_code);
        });
    }
```

So I want to have something similar with users table as well, but I am having issues , the page hangs and loads error 500

Comment: try to check Auth::hasUser() and the fetch auth user if it exists

Comment: check the error log to see what is causing the 500 error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using this global scope on User model.

when you call `auth()->user()` it will call `User::find(auth()->id())` and as you are using `auth()->user()` within global scope. it causes infinite recursive call to itself. To avoid this you can use Query Bilder like instead of using `auth()->id()` you can use:

$user = \DB::table('users')->where('id', auth()->id())->first();